# I am unable to remove index.php from URl in codeigniter 3.1.11

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried adding **.htaccess** in root folder from the documentation available. i searched all over the internet but nothing solved my problem.

code inside .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

made a changes in apache file **httpd**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: may be permission issue. need to check permission first.

Comment: Can you please list what you have tried so far? I don't know anything about this topic but those that do would be able to give you a quicker answer if you eliminate already tried approaches.

Comment: It is unclear, what you try to achieve here. Do you want to remove index.php from the filesystem? Then this has nothing to do with rewrite rules and the given config files. If you want to protect index.php from outside access, this should be clarified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find the below code
 $config['index_page'] = "index.php"
Remove index.php
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Write below code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes i did the same, but i didn't get the result. I added this in .htaccess on root. Do i need to place in other .htacces file as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this 
issue just open the file config.php located in application/config and then find and 
replace the code as:

  Find the below code

 $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"

  Replace it as

 $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```